# Shared Preferences Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store the value of the settings of my app on SharedPreferences, but after the first run, I keep getting this error when trying to open the Settings Activity.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{me.leofontes.driversed2/me.leofontes.driversed2.Settings}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x41 

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
```

This is my code, everything works great when I remove the SharedPreferences..

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "SettingsSharedPrefs";
    public static final String TOTAL_KEY = "total";
    public static final String DAY_KEY = "day";
    public static final String NIGHT_KEY = "night";
    public static final String RESIDENTIAL_KEY = "residential";
    public static final String COMMERCIAL_KEY = "commercial";
    public static final String HIGHWAY_KEY = "highway";
    public static final String CLEAR_KEY = "clear";
    public static final String RAINY_KEY = "rainy";
    public static final String SNOWY_KEY = "snowy";

    EditText totalHours;
    EditText dayHours;
    EditText nightHours;
    EditText resHours;
    EditText comHours;
    EditText hwHours;
    EditText clearHours;
    EditText rainyHours;
    EditText snowyHours;

    private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor pEditor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_settings);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    totalHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.totalHoursInput);
    dayHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dayHoursInput);
    nightHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nightHoursInput);
    resHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.resHoursInput);
    comHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comHoursInput);
    hwHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hwHoursInput);
    clearHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.clearHoursInput);
    rainyHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rainyHoursInput);
    snowyHours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.snowyHoursInput);


    //Manage Shared Preferences
    Context context = getApplicationContext();  // app level storage
    myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    pEditor = myPrefs.edit();

    if(myPrefs.getInt(TOTAL_KEY, -1) == -1) {
        pEditor.putInt(TOTAL_KEY, Integer.parseInt(totalHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(DAY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(dayHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(NIGHT_KEY, Integer.parseInt(nightHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(RESIDENTIAL_KEY, Integer.parseInt(resHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(COMMERCIAL_KEY, Integer.parseInt(comHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(HIGHWAY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(hwHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(CLEAR_KEY, Integer.parseInt(clearHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(RAINY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(rainyHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.putInt(SNOWY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(snowyHours.getText().toString()));
        pEditor.commit();
    } else {
        totalHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(TOTAL_KEY, 65));
        dayHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(DAY_KEY, 55));
        nightHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(NIGHT_KEY, 10));
        resHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(RESIDENTIAL_KEY, 4));
        comHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(COMMERCIAL_KEY, 2));
        hwHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(HIGHWAY_KEY, 4));
        clearHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(CLEAR_KEY, 55));
        rainyHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(RAINY_KEY, 5));
        snowyHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(SNOWY_KEY, 5));
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    pEditor.putInt(TOTAL_KEY, Integer.parseInt(totalHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(DAY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(dayHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(NIGHT_KEY, Integer.parseInt(nightHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(RESIDENTIAL_KEY, Integer.parseInt(resHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(COMMERCIAL_KEY, Integer.parseInt(comHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(HIGHWAY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(hwHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(CLEAR_KEY, Integer.parseInt(clearHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(RAINY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(rainyHours.getText().toString()));
    pEditor.putInt(SNOWY_KEY, Integer.parseInt(snowyHours.getText().toString()));

    pEditor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

Thank you! If any other information is needed, happy to supply! I think it's something trivial but I can't figure out the correct way to do this.

Comment: check logcat and post the line number of error

Comment: You need to put a String in there otherwise, It's looking for a resource with that id in the `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so what you're running into here is a common pitfall. As you're storing your values in the `SharedPreferences`, you're storing them explicitly as a integer. Later on when you're retrieving them, you're trying to set the text with the direct integer value (pretty much how one would try to do it) as seen below:

`totalHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(TOTAL_KEY, 65));
dayHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(DAY_KEY, 55));
nightHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(NIGHT_KEY, 10));
resHours.setText(myPrefs.getInt(RESIDENTIAL_KEY, 4));
//...`

The problem here is however that when you provide the `setText(int)` method with an int, it'll try to set the text to the value of the string resource with an id that matches your value. If you're really lucky, the app will actually find a string resource (albeit faulty) and set it, but in most cases you'll get the error you're seeing above.

The solution to this problem would be to wrap your `myPrefs.getInt(...)` calls with `String.valueOf(...)`, which will convert your integers to strings and subsequently call the `setText(String)` method on the `TextView` (avoiding the whole resource shebang).

Hope that clears up the problem you're seeing!

Comment: Thank you very much! Makes a lot of sense, I knew it was something simple but I was not finding it, thanks